# Gephi fails to import Neo4j data

Tags: java, neo4j, gephi

I got this message as I tried to import Neo4j database to Gephi:

> org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException: Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true"
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.ConfigMapUpgradeConfiguration.checkConfigurationAllowsAutomaticUpgrade(ConfigMapUpgradeConfiguration.java:41)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.attemptUpgrade(StoreUpgrader.java:50)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NeoStore.tryToUpgradeStores(NeoStore.java:170)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NeoStore.checkVersion(NeoStore.java:137)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.(CommonAbstractStore.java:104)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.AbstractStore.(AbstractStore.java:120)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NeoStore.(NeoStore.java:78)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:165)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.create(XaDataSourceManager.java:77)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxModule.registerDataSource(TxModule.java:152)
>   Caused: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Could not create data source [nioneodb], see nested exception for cause of error
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxModule.registerDataSource(TxModule.java:158)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.GraphDbInstance.start(GraphDbInstance.java:105)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDbImpl.(EmbeddedGraphDbImpl.java:190)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:80)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:64)
>       at org.gephi.desktop.neo4j.ui.util.Neo4jUtils.localDatabase(Neo4jUtils.java:43)
>       at org.gephi.desktop.neo4j.Neo4jMenuAction$FullImportMenuAction.actionPerformed(Neo4jMenuAction.java:218)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
>       at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:158)
>   [catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Curiously, configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true" is already set to true.
I am using neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06, and Java version is:

> java version "1.7.0_45"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

What am I supposed to do? Java version is the latest, and so Neo4j...

Answer (score 0):

[Wes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/683201/wes-freeman) gave me a clue, as I have upgraded Neo4j to 2.0 version, I cannot open anything in Gephi.

Comment: The gephi plugin is not yet upgraded to Neo4j 2.0, perhaps you can ping the @gephi guys about that?

Comment: Did anyone find out when Gephi will support Neo4j 2.0?